# Typo3 4.5.5 and Typo3 4.6.8 backend login doesn't work?

Tags: php, typo3

Recently I couldn't access the backend with my Typo3 4.5.5. First off I thought I forgot my password but because I've physical access to my database I can verify that. I can access the install tool and create me a new user but to no avail. I've updated my typo3 version to 4.6.8 to no avail. I can use Typo3 4.7.0 but some of my extensions needs a workaround because it doesn't work with 4.7.0. What can be the reason my user cannot access the backend? I don't have any php error in the logs. For developement I'm using a virtual machine with Suse 12.2 and lighttpd + FastCGI, php 5.3.8, xdebug 2.2.0RC2 and Komodo IDE. Mysql is from suse repository so it's something 5+.

Comment: Can you write information? Linux or Windows? Have you looked to you error logs? The last time we had changes the encryption for the backend and this module wasn't available under windows

Comment: @Stony: For developement I'm using a virtual machine with Suse 12.2 and lighttpd + FastCGI, php 5.3.8, xdebug 2.2.0RC2 and Komodo IDE. Mysql is from suse repository so it's something 5+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhpas you activated the rsaauth Extension and you are having some special characters in your password? Try to change it to an simple ANSI-only password for testing purpose.

Perhaps try to delete related cookies or use an fresh/different browser.

Check your settings in INSTALL-Tool, perhaps you locked your Session to a wrong domain / IP?

Comment: Do you know for sure? What is changed in T3 4.7? I don't have any special character nor this extension or ip lock or anything because it's my developement server.

Comment: It's because I didn't specify a correct path for my session variable in my php ini: session.save_path = /usr/lib64/php5????? Problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: A not writable session dir is a common problem for login.